# Subir imagen desde react native a backend php (laravel)

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, react-native, fetch

Hola quiero subir una imagen desde mi app con react native y recibirla en mi backend programada con laravel

mi código que sube la pantalla es la siguiente

```
  _takePick = async () => {
    await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA, Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
    const datarray = [];
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
      allowsEditing: false,
      //exif: true,
      quality: 1,

    })
    datarray.push({
      uri: result.uri,
      type: result.type+"/jpg",
      width: result.width,
      height: result.height,
      cancelled: result.cancelled,
      perro: "perro",
    });
    this.setState({ datapick: datarray });
    console.log(this.state.datapick);
    if (!result.cancelled) {
      this.setState({ image: result.uri });
    }
  };


  _uploadfile = async () => {

    console.log( JSON.stringify(this.state.datapick));
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('image',this.state.datapick);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    console.log(data);
    fetch('http://ruta_de_mi_apirest/api/Foto/uploadfile', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'accept-charset':"UTF-8",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).then(Response=>{
      console.log(Response);
    }).then(err=>{
      console.log(err);
    });

  }
```

ahi muestro dos funciones la _takepick lo que hace es abrir la cámara del telefono y tomar una foto, esta foto toma sus propiedades y se la añado a un variable array y la segunda funcion _uploadfile es la funcion que sube la foto o imagen al servidor donde se aloja mi backend,

el siguiente codigo es la funcion que recibe lo enviado a trabes del apirest

la verdad es que para esta función no tengo mucha idea no se como recibir la imagen, **cabe recalcar como se ve en la funcion _uploadfile estoy enviando en multipart/form-daa**

```
 public function uploadfile(Request $request){


        $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
        $obj = json_decode($json, true);

        dd($json,$obj['_parts'][0],    $request->file());
    }
```

que estoy haciendo mal o que me falta?

Answer (score 2):

No es necesario el JSON.stringify. 
Puede intentar de esta forma.

```
const data = new FormData();
data.append('image', {
    uri: this.state.image,
    name: 'capturamovil.jpg',
    type: 'image/jpg'
  });
fetch('http://ruta_de_mi_apirest/api/Foto/uploadfile', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
     'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
  },
  body: data
}).then(Response=>{
  console.log(Response);
}).then(err=>{
  console.log(err);
});
```

y en laravel la puede recibir.

```
 public function uploadfile(Request $request){
  $img="default.png";
    if($request->hasFile('image')){
        $file = $request->file('image');
        $img = time().$file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move(public_path().'/images/',$img);
    }   
 }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! lo voy a aplicar y te cuento!

Comment: estimado disculpa la tardanza, recien lo pude probar, pero me da el siguiente error

Comment: Enviame el error